# How to get rid of an ssl security warning with expired certificate

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

In the past I had a ssl certificate but I don't have it anymore because I didn't use it. However, now I see that some of the my website's page are indexed on google with https. Clicking those links directs you to a security warning. How can I best solve this? I tried adjusting the htaccess file redirect https requests to the http protocol, but that doesn't remove the warning. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing you can do except renew your certificate.

The warning is opened by your browser, **before** any request is ever even sent to the server. When it tries to resolve an HTTPS request, it first establishes the SSL handshake with the server, this is where the server gives the browser the certificate and the browser sees that it's expired. The browser then displays a security exception/warning. That means there is *nothing* that you can do on the server's end to prevent this from happening except addressing the certificate.

After you've renewed your cert, you need to have a rule to redirect all HTTPS traffic to HTTP traffic using a 301 redirect.